# SSRS Parameters Data Parameters Failing on Data Driven Subscription

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, parameters

I'm wondering if anyone is able to help.

I have a suite of data driven subscriptions which uses the following SQL Code to calculate the parameter.  This is the same SQL Server data source that the report uses too.

```
 select cast(dateadd(day,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) in (5,6) then 4 else 2 end,getdate()) as date) [parameter]
```

The parameter in the report is of type date.

This has been working for 15 months no problem but following a server upgrade last week, this is now stopped working.  When investigating, the error log said that the above was not giving a valid date.  If I manually enter a date in the report itself it works fine.  If I specify a hard coded date in the subscription, and look at the report, the results now appear to be reversing the month and day parts of the date (for when that option gives a valid date).

As a temporary work around in the critical reports, I've managed to get this working by converting the result to varchar in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd' by changing the code to this:

```
select left(convert(varchar,dateadd(day,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) in (5,6) then 4 else 2 end,getdate()),126),10) [parameter]
```

Because of the volume of reports affected, it's not necessarily practical to do this for all the reports.

Any ideas for causes and potential fixes?

Answer (score 0):

I can see a reason to your code generates an error. You can get wrong results because of the configuration of SET DATEFIRST on the server.

First, check your Datadirst with

```
SELECT @@DATEFIRST
```

And set it in your code like it

```
DECLARE @Date date = '20170914' -- Thursday


SET DATEFIRST 1 ; 
SELECT datepart(dw,@Date) 
--Result 4 

SET DATEFIRST 2 ; 
SELECT datepart(dw,@Date) 
--Result 3

SET DATEFIRST 3 ; 
SELECT datepart(dw,@Date) 
--Result 2

SET DATEFIRST 4 ; 
SELECT datepart(dw,@Date) 
--Result 1

SET DATEFIRST 5 ; 
SELECT datepart(dw,@Date) 
--Result 7

SET DATEFIRST 6 ; 
SELECT datepart(dw,@Date) 
--Result 6

SET DATEFIRST 7 ; 
SELECT datepart(dw,@Date) 
--Result 5
```

[SET DATEFIRST (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql)

[SET DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql)

[SET LANGUAGE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql)

Comment: I see: However, I'm not sure why that would make a difference as what appears to be happening is that the date returned by the code I posted is working correctly.

What is going wrong is that it's behaving as if I've hard coded the date in the wrong format despite the fact I've not hard-coded any of the data.

Comment: I understand, I inferred the fisrtdate because you did not post the error only the description and I had a similar problem some weeks ago and it was the solution.

Comment: I didn't post the error as SSRS doesn't actually tell me what the error is.  All it says is: `Done: 1 processed of 1 total; 1 errors.`

Comment: If the report is running on the server, you can try this article to get de error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-service-trace-log or this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-log-files-and-sources

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have access to the file locations on the server: only SSRS element.

Comment: Have found out that this is a wider issue with one of the Microsoft Updates to Server 2012 and how applications in .NET frameworks 4.0+ behave.